# Python & OpenCV - Trying to turn transparent pixels into white nontransparent pixels

Tags: python, opencv

I'm relatively new to data processing using OpenCV. For a machine learning project, I'm trying to process images so that all the transparent pixels will be turned into white nontransparent pixels for my GAN to use. However, I keep on getting an error when trying to process it. 
Here is my code below /

```
    img = cv2.imread(dirfName, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED) (Note Dirftname is a defined variable)
    for col in img:                        
        for row in img[col]:                
            if(img[col,row] == (0,0,0,0)):                    
                    img[col,row] = (255,255,255,255)

    cv2.imwrite((fCropPath + fNameIndent + fname), new_img)
```

The error is with the if statement and it states: 
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: I get [over 700 matches](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ValueError%3A+The+truth+value+of+an+array+with+more+than+one+element+is+ambiguous.+Use+a.any%28%29+or+a.all%28%29) when I search for that exact error message on Stack Overflow. Perhaps at least one has some relevant information?

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam the tag (removed).

Answer (score 0):

Note your syntax in the itterations, `row` and `col` are not indexes.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread(dirfName, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
for col in img:
    for row in col:
        if(row.__eq__(0).all()): # This is what you want
                row += 255

cv2.imwrite((fCropPath + fNameIndent + fname), new_img)
```

`row.__eq__(0).all()` is equivalent to `np.all(row == 0)`

Furthermore, it is better practice to vectorize your loops:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread(dirfName, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
ind = np.equal(img, 0).all(axis=2)
img[ind] = np.array([255]*4)

cv2.imwrite((fCropPath + fNameIndent + fname), new_img)
```

The above code does exactly the same thing but vectorized.